# Bash - find a keyword in a file and delete its line

Tags: bash, sed, grep, command-line-interface, replace

I'd like to give a keyword, find the line where this keyword aṕpears in a file and erase the entire line.

This is what I got but it is not working as it should:

```
KEYWORD='domain.com'
cat /etc/hosts | grep -v "$KEYWORD" > /etc/hosts
```

**UPDATE**

This is what worked for me:

`sed -i_bak -e '/domain\.com/d' /etc/hosts`

However, as I had two lines with "domain.com", is there a way to tell sed to erase only the line where the exact keyword "domain.com" appears

This is the original content of /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost       localhost.localdomain
222.111.22.222      hvn.domain.com
222.111.22.222      domain.com
```

Here's how it end up after the command `sed -i_bak -e '/domain\.com/d' /etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost       localhost.localdomain
```

I tried `sed -i_bak -e '/\<namourphoto\.com\.br\>/d' ~/Desktop/hosts` but it didn't work.

**CONCLUSION**

This is the code I came up with (based on the help the fine folks have given me):

```
D=domain.com
DOMAIN=`echo "$D" | sed 's/\./\\\\./g'`
sed -i_bak -e "/[\t]$DOMAIN/d" /etc/hosts
```

Note that:

- I am counting that there is always a tab before the domain to be erased
- I am automatically escaping the dots of the domain name.

Comment: Please also note that dot has special meaning in regexps so `domain.com` will also match `domainxcom.net`. You should escape the dot.

Comment: Must I escape dots even when between ''?

Comment: Yes, you do. Try `echo abc | grep 'a.c'`, the output will be `abc`.

Comment: I wrote a code (above) to do escape the dots automatically

Comment: add a space to the `[\t]` part, since /etc/hosts is whitespace separated.

Comment: How can I write the regex to choose from space or tab?

Comment: What if I let the option of a space or a tab? (In my case, it's a tab). Would this be right? /[:space:\t]$DOMAIN/d

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the [stream editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), sed:

```
sed -i ".bak" '/culpa/d' test.txt
```

The above will delete lines containing *culpa* in test.txt. It will create a backup of the original (named test.txt.bak) and will modify the original file in-place.

Comment: My tests didn't work with the space among -i and .bak. But when I pu -i.bak it did work.

Comment: how do you do this while discarding the original without making backup? UPDATE: just made the ".bak" quote blank to answer my own question.

Comment: in my case keyword is ipaddress with `.` and port `:`
IS this right?
`sed -i "/$proxy[^0-9]/d" proxy.txt`

Answer (score 7):

Pipe it to another file, not the same one that you're reading from, and be careful with the useless use of `cat`.

```
grep -v "$KEYWORD" /etc/hosts > newfile
```

---

Apart from the fine answer given regarding sed, you can also use Perl and a little improved regex to solve this:

```
perl -pi.old -e 's/.*\sdomain\.com\s*\n//' file
```

Notice I'm considering `domain.com` will be isolated by space characters (tabs or spaces, and so on), and that nothing but zero or more spaces will appear after it until the newline. Similarly to `-i` in sed,
`-i.old` in perl sets the `$^I` variable, and your original file will receive the changes while a copy will be kept under the old name and a `.old` appended.

Comment: Is there a way to edit in place with this approach or I always need to make another file in order to edit it?

Comment: Very elegant your code, thank you.

Comment: @Roger: De nada, e bonito cachorro. Será que essa área verde aí atrás é aqui em SP? :P

Comment: origado, é um Akita. Sim, a paisagem é no Morro do Ouro, em Apiaí; conhece?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only delete last line of your example file

```
sed -i '/[[:space:]]\+domain\.com/d' test.txt
```