# find & sed: remove lines

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to delete some line in PHP files. I tried to use an find, exec combination:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec sed '/@category/d' {} \;
```

but it only prints out the files contents. Is there anythin wrong in the syntax? Or what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try this command:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec sed -i '/@category/d' {} \;
```

I think you've missed -i option

Answer (score 1):

It works, but probably not how you expect.

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec sed -i '/@category/d' {} \;
```

Will kill the lines in question.

Answer (score 1):

This should be the command for sed so try to add -i :

`sed -i ".bak" '/culpa/d' test.txt`

`find . -name '*.php' -exec sed -i '/@category/d' {} \;`

Source of the answer:
[Bash - find a keyword in a file and delete its line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050717/bash-find-a-keyword-in-a-file-and-delete-its-line)